# Salesforce OAuth Token endpoint certificate not accepted

Tags: apexrest, certificates, rest-service

We're currently working with Bank of America to provide an exposed Rest Service that they can use to send in financial data.  We are currently running into a roadblock, in that they aren't able to validate trust with the OAuth token endpoint.  We have OAuth set for the client credentials flow and have shared the appropriate information with Bank of America, but they are failing to validate the SSL certificate on the token url.

Does anyone know what certifying authority/authorities need to be in their chain of trust to accept the cert attached to apex rest service endpoints?

Comment: _they are failing to validate the SSL certificate on the token url_ : what endpoint are they using? It's likely the way their client contacts your service, e.g. they have a proxy in the middle.